# What is the meanings and relation of electron negative charge from Coulomb Law perspective

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

Electron is defined to have negative charge. From many questions we can see here in Stack Exchange we conclude that charge is a property of a particle in an electromagnetic field.

But as we learning in High school the negative charge have a tendency to attract another positive charge.

By Coulomb’s law
$$F = \frac{k Q_1 Q_2}{r^2}$$

we see the relation with resulting force with two charges. That means if a negative charge in modulus is bigger than the positive, let me assume that $Q_1 = -10$ and $Q_2 = 5$.

I can conclude that the negative charge will push the positive?

Otherwise if positive Q are bigger setting $Q_2=50$ and $Q_1= -10$ the final signal force is still negative because $Q_1$ is negative, right?

What thoughts can I get from this?

So can we at least say that charge is where the particles tend to move?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to note.  First, the electron having a negative charge is simply a matter of convention.  That is, we have all agreed to that notation, but there is nothing unique about the electron that dictates that it must be a negative charge.

Second, you seem to imply that the larger charge will be the one to win out so that if Q1 is -10 and Q2 is 5 that it is the larger -10 charge that will push Q2 away. This is where you make your error.  Both particles exert a force on each other proportional to their charge.  (Just as in gravity where both Earth and the moon exert a gravitational attraction.) We know that gravity is always attractive and electrostatic force may be attractive or repulsive.  The fact that Q1 and Q2 have different signs (one positive and one negative) simply means the net result will be attractive (the old saying - opposites attract).  So, your first example is actually wrong.  The -10 charge does not push the +5 charge away.  The two charges will attract each other because they have opposite charges.

If I read your question correctly, you then suggest that if Q2 is a much larger positive charge (50) vs. Q1 at -10 that the large positive charge should win out.
This is incorrect.  Once again, since the two charges are opposite, the result will be an attractive force.  But the magnitude of the force is determined by both charges (just as required in Coulomb's law).  You multiply the two charges together.  If the sign for the two charges are opposite, it is an attractive force. If both charges are the same (both negative or both positive) it will be a repulsive force.

Comment: Thanks for such amizing answer @JRL. If you could share with me some good materials to improve my knowlegd in these area it would be nice.

Comment: Nothing specific to recommend, but any intro to physics textbook should give you a good overview of electrostatics and Coulomb's law.